# How to add mongodb to your private network unable to find plugin: eosio::mongo_db_plugin

Tags: testnet, database, private-blockchain, storage, plugin

I am trying to setup mongodb on private network node on cent OS 7 based server but it throws error unable to find plugin: eosio::mongo_db_plugin. I have uncommented mongo plugin settings in config.ini.
Currently I am Using

- cent OS 7
- eosio v 1.8.7 & eosio.cdt v 1.6.3 (using prebuilt binaries)
- nodeos -v 1.8.6
  Here is my config.ini

```
#bnet-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:4321

# this peer will request only irreversible blocks from other nodes (eosio::bnet_plugin)
#bnet-follow-irreversible = 0

# the number of threads to use to process network messages (eosio::bnet_plugin)
# bnet-threads = 

# remote endpoint of other node to connect to; Use multiple bnet-connect options as needed to compose a network (eosio::bnet_plugin)
# bnet-connect = 

# this peer will request no pending transactions from other nodes (eosio::bnet_plugin)
#bnet-no-trx = false

# The string used to format peers when logging messages about them.  Variables are escaped with ${<variable name>}.
# Available Variables:
#    _name      self-reported name
# 
#    _id        self-reported ID (Public Key)
# 
#    _ip        remote IP address of peer
# 
#    _port      remote port number of peer
# 
#    _lip       local IP address connected to peer
# 
#    _lport     local port number connected to peer
# 
#  (eosio::bnet_plugin)
#bnet-peer-log-format = ["${_name}" ${_ip}:${_port}]

# the location of the blocks directory (absolute path or relative to application data dir) (eosio::chain_plugin)
blocks-dir = "blocks"

# Pairs of [BLOCK_NUM,BLOCK_ID] that should be enforced as checkpoints. (eosio::chain_plugin)
# checkpoint = 

# Override default WASM runtime (eosio::chain_plugin)
# wasm-runtime = 

# Override default maximum ABI serialization time allowed in ms (eosio::chain_plugin)
abi-serializer-max-time-ms = 15000

# Maximum size (in MiB) of the chain state database (eosio::chain_plugin)
chain-state-db-size-mb = 30720

# Safely shut down node when free space remaining in the chain state database drops below this size (in MiB). (eosio::chain_plugin)
chain-state-db-guard-size-mb = 1280

# Maximum size (in MiB) of the reversible blocks database (eosio::chain_plugin)
reversible-blocks-db-size-mb = 340

# Safely shut down node when free space remaining in the reverseible blocks database drops below this size (in MiB). (eosio::chain_plugin)
reversible-blocks-db-guard-size-mb = 20

# print contract's output to console (eosio::chain_plugin)
contracts-console = true

# Account added to actor whitelist (may specify multiple times) (eosio::chain_plugin)
# actor-whitelist = 

# Account added to actor blacklist (may specify multiple times) (eosio::chain_plugin)
# actor-blacklist = 

# Contract account added to contract whitelist (may specify multiple times) (eosio::chain_plugin)
# contract-whitelist = 

# Contract account added to contract blacklist (may specify multiple times) (eosio::chain_plugin)
# contract-blacklist = 

# Action (in the form code::action) added to action blacklist (may specify multiple times) (eosio::chain_plugin)
# action-blacklist = 

# Public key added to blacklist of keys that should not be included in authorities (may specify multiple times) (eosio::chain_plugin)
# key-blacklist = 

# Database read mode ("speculative", "head", or "read-only").
# In "speculative" mode database contains changes done up to the head block plus changes made by transactions not yet included to the blockchain.
# In "head" mode database contains changes done up to the current head block.
# In "read-only" mode database contains incoming block changes but no speculative transaction processing.
#  (eosio::chain_plugin)
read-mode = speculative

# Chain validation mode ("full" or "light").
# In "full" mode all incoming blocks will be fully validated.
# In "light" mode all incoming blocks headers will be fully validated; transactions in those validated blocks will be trusted 
#  (eosio::chain_plugin)
validation-mode = light

# Disable the check which subjectively fails a transaction if a contract bills more RAM to another account within the context of a notification handler (i.e. when the receiver is not the code of the action). (eosio::chain_plugin)
disable-ram-billing-notify-checks = false

# Indicate a producer whose blocks headers signed by it will be fully validated, but transactions in those validated blocks will be trusted. (eosio::chain_plugin)
# trusted-producer = 

# Track actions which match receiver:action:actor. Actor may be blank to include all. Action and Actor both blank allows all from Recieiver. Receiver may not be blank. (eosio::history_plugin)
# filter-on = 

# Do not track actions which match receiver:action:actor. Action and Actor both blank excludes all from Reciever. Actor blank excludes all from reciever:action. Receiver may not be blank. (eosio::history_plugin)
# filter-out = 

# PEM encoded trusted root certificate (or path to file containing one) used to validate any TLS connections made.  (may specify multiple times)
#  (eosio::http_client_plugin)
# https-client-root-cert = 

# true: validate that the peer certificates are valid and trusted, false: ignore cert errors (eosio::http_client_plugin)
https-client-validate-peers = false

# The local IP and port to listen for incoming http connections; set blank to disable. (eosio::http_plugin)
http-server-address = 0.0.0.0:8888

# The local IP and port to listen for incoming https connections; leave blank to disable. (eosio::http_plugin)
https-server-address = 0.0.0.0:8899

# Filename with the certificate chain to present on https connections. PEM format. Required for https. (eosio::http_plugin)
https-certificate-chain-file = /home/eos-cert/cert.pem

# Filename with https private key in PEM format. Required for https (eosio::http_plugin)
https-private-key-file = /home/eos-cert/key.pem

# Specify the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to be returned on each request. (eosio::http_plugin)
access-control-allow-origin =  *

# Specify the Access-Control-Allow-Headers to be returned on each request. (eosio::http_plugin)
# access-control-allow-headers = 

# Specify the Access-Control-Max-Age to be returned on each request. (eosio::http_plugin)
# access-control-max-age = 

# Specify if Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true should be returned on each request. (eosio::http_plugin)
access-control-allow-credentials = false

# The maximum body size in bytes allowed for incoming RPC requests (eosio::http_plugin)
max-body-size = 1048576

# Append the error log to HTTP responses (eosio::http_plugin)
verbose-http-errors = true

# If set to false, then any incoming "Host" header is considered valid (eosio::http_plugin)
http-validate-host = 1 

# Additionaly acceptable values for the "Host" header of incoming HTTP requests, can be specified multiple times.  Includes http/s_server_address by default. (eosio::http_plugin)
# http-alias = 

# The maximum number of pending login requests (eosio::login_plugin)
max-login-requests = 1000000

# The maximum timeout for pending login requests (in seconds) (eosio::login_plugin)
max-login-timeout = 60

# The target queue size between nodeos and MongoDB plugin thread. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)
mongodb-queue-size = 2048

# The maximum size of the abi cache for serializing data. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)
mongodb-abi-cache-size = 2048

# Required with --replay-blockchain, --hard-replay-blockchain, or --delete-all-blocks to wipe mongo db.This option required to prevent accidental wipe of mongo db. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)
mongodb-wipe = true

# If specified then only abi data pushed to mongodb until specified block is reached. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)
#mongodb-block-start = 1

# MongoDB URI connection string, see: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/connection-string/. If not specified then plugin is disabled. Default database 'EOS' is used if not specified in URI. Example: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/EOS (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)
mongodb-uri = mongodb://wizz:54321@127.0.0.1:27777
#mongodb-uri = mongodb://104.156.59.184:27017
#mongodb-uri = mongodb://wizz:54321@127.0.0.1:27017 

# Update blocks/block_state with latest via block number so that duplicates are overwritten. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)
#mongodb-update-via-block-num = 1

# Enables storing blocks in mongodb. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)

mongodb-store-blocks = 1

# Enables storing block state in mongodb. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)

mongodb-store-block-states = 1

# Enables storing transactions in mongodb. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)
mongodb-store-transactions = 1

# Enables storing transaction traces in mongodb. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)
mongodb-store-transaction-traces = 1

# Enables storing action traces in mongodb. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)

mongodb-store-action-traces = 1

# Track actions which match receiver:action:actor. Receiver, Action, & Actor may be blank to include all. i.e. eosio:: or :transfer:  Use * or leave unspecified to include all. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)
mongodb-filter-on = *

# Do not track actions which match receiver:action:actor. Receiver, Action, & Actor may be blank to exclude all. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)
mongodb-filter-out = eosio:onblock:
mongodb-filter-out = gu2tembqgage::
mongodb-filter-out = blocktwitter:

# The actual host:port used to listen for incoming p2p connections. (eosio::net_plugin)
p2p-listen-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:4444

# An externally accessible host:port for identifying this node. Defaults to p2p-listen-endpoint. (eosio::net_plugin)
#p2p-server-address = 0.0.0.0:9021 

# The public endpoint of a peer node to connect to. Use multiple p2p-peer-address options as needed to compose a network. (eosio::net_plugin)
#p2p-peer-address = 0.0.0.0:9021 

# Maximum number of client nodes from any single IP address (eosio::net_plugin)
p2p-max-nodes-per-host = 1

# The name supplied to identify this node amongst the peers. (eosio::net_plugin)
agent-name = "WIZZ EOS Agent"

# Can be 'any' or 'producers' or 'specified' or 'none'. If 'specified', peer-key must be specified at least once. If only 'producers', peer-key is not required. 'producers' and 'specified' may be combined. (eosio::net_plugin)
allowed-connection = any

# Optional public key of peer allowed to connect.  May be used multiple times. (eosio::net_plugin)
# peer-key = 

# Tuple of [PublicKey, WIF private key] (may specify multiple times) (eosio::net_plugin)
# peer-private-key = 

# Maximum number of clients from which connections are accepted, use 0 for no limit (eosio::net_plugin)
max-clients = 25

# number of seconds to wait before cleaning up dead connections (eosio::net_plugin)
connection-cleanup-period = 30

# max connection cleanup time per cleanup call in millisec (eosio::net_plugin)
max-cleanup-time-msec = 10

# True to require exact match of peer network version. (eosio::net_plugin)
network-version-match = 0

# number of blocks to retrieve in a chunk from any individual peer during synchronization (eosio::net_plugin)
sync-fetch-span = 2000

# maximum sizes of transaction or block messages that are sent without first sending a notice (eosio::net_plugin)
#max-implicit-request = 1500

# Enable expirimental socket read watermark optimization (eosio::net_plugin)
use-socket-read-watermark = 0

# The string used to format peers when logging messages about them.  Variables are escaped with ${<variable name>}.
# Available Variables:
#    _name      self-reported name
# 
#    _id        self-reported ID (64 hex characters)
# 
#    _sid       first 8 characters of _peer.id
# 
#    _ip        remote IP address of peer
# 
#    _port      remote port number of peer
# 
#    _lip       local IP address connected to peer
# 
#    _lport     local port number connected to peer
# 
#  (eosio::net_plugin)
peer-log-format = ["${_name}" ${_ip}:${_port}]

# Enable block production, even if the chain is stale. (eosio::producer_plugin)
enable-stale-production = true

# Start this node in a state where production is paused (eosio::producer_plugin)
pause-on-startup = false

# Limits the maximum time (in milliseconds) that is allowed a pushed transaction's code to execute before being considered invalid (eosio::producer_plugin)
max-transaction-time = 30

# Limits the maximum age (in seconds) of the DPOS Irreversible Block for a chain this node will produce blocks on (use negative value to indicate unlimited) (eosio::producer_plugin)
max-irreversible-block-age = -1

# ID of producer controlled by this node (e.g. inita; may specify multiple times) (eosio::producer_plugin)
producer-name = eosio     
# (DEPRECATED - Use signature-provider instead) Tuple of [public key, WIF private key] (may specify multiple times) (eosio::producer_plugin)
# private-key = 

# Key=Value pairs in the form <public-key>=<provider-spec>
# Where:
#    <public-key>       is a string form of a vaild EOSIO public key
# 
#    <provider-spec>    is a string in the form <provider-type>:<data>
# 
#    <provider-type>    is KEY, or KEOSD
# 
#    KEY:<data>         is a string form of a valid EOSIO private key which maps to the provided public key
#  

#    KEOSD:<data>       is the URL where keosd is available and the approptiate wallet(s) are unlocked (eosio::producer_plugin)
#signature-provider = EOS8Xf4dTbF3DkynCH7ixVwAnwHEVVJoadZR9czYH6Z5vpDHgvTWY=KEY:5J4s7rY9iVG4cgsu4qnRoF4tMjxEcFvjs8qurh7YhRVvWLg18M4
#signature-provider = EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV=KEY:5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3
#signature-provider = EOS64mMHs56ELYjdqYomy4Bu6S3Ept6e84ptXjwN3u5EmXPFSSSx8=KEY:5KBVkWahHShb1AqDiLgSuzxLv4AXMGdgJsZ5ZCDKSaqjpFYDs5y
#signature-provider = EOS83iGMnSmVGEa6LLVJ3p2DZMWCjQwhXmJQVJ13MQBQCUSV1bcxA=KEY:5KJmVY3HL458P2HhpKvMwSnSwibcGuadk5BzK8fiL7UpVvtUqBx
#signature-provider = EOS76ENexj7UXcL3Ns28fLMNCDKgpuKxB2Vg8V8bWFnWJvYzpKyHg=KEY:5JqjhdpFLkQUGgM6MHNz256jA8ZtifwMXQYUd7UtdU5HbEy8Rzx
signature-provider = EOS8bAgZz8MaaR9nkesupV6c3AWNzSQA4CBsC1ykDNwgZLEAzoZiM=KEY:5K4Pk8SgwnRxBscUPuZ4jB4YXncubibqd7EYdWfW3fKVyiDjKJe
# Limits the maximum time (in milliseconds) that is allowd for sending blocks to a keosd provider for signing (eosio::producer_plugin)
keosd-provider-timeout = 5

# account that can not access to extended CPU/NET virtual resources (eosio::producer_plugin)
# greylist-account = 

# offset of non last block producing time in microseconds. Negative number results in blocks to go out sooner, and positive number results in blocks to go out later (eosio::producer_plugin)
produce-time-offset-us = 0

# offset of last block producing time in microseconds. Negative number results in blocks to go out sooner, and positive number results in blocks to go out later (eosio::producer_plugin)
last-block-time-offset-us = 0

# ratio between incoming transations and deferred transactions when both are exhausted (eosio::producer_plugin)
incoming-defer-ratio = 1

# the location of the snapshots directory (absolute path or relative to application data dir) (eosio::producer_plugin)
snapshots-dir = "snapshots"

# Lag in number of blocks from the head block when selecting the reference block for transactions (-1 means Last Irreversible Block) (eosio::txn_test_gen_plugin)
txn-reference-block-lag = 0

# Plugin(s) to enable, may be specified multiple times
# plugin = 
# plugin = eosio::chain_plugin
# plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
# plugin = eosio::net_api_plugin
# plugin = eosio::history_plugin
# plugin = eosio::history_api_plugin
# plugin = eosio::wallet_plugin
# plugin = eosio::wallet_api_plugin
# plugin = eosio::http_plugin
# plugin = eosio::http_client_plugin

plugin = eosio::producer_plugin
plugin = eosio::producer_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::net_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::net_plugin
plugin = eosio::http_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_plugin
plugin = eosio::history_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::history_plugin
plugin = eosio::db_size_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::mongo_db_plugin

#Other Peers
p2p-peer-address= 104.156.59.184:4444
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `plugin = eosio::mongo_db_plugin` to your config.ini.

If error doesn't disappears, it could be that nodeos you use wasn't built with mongo_db_plugin. mongo_db_plugin was deprecated, so it can be omitted intentionally. Then, you need to build nodeos by yourself. `scripts/eosio_build.sh -m` will build nodeos with mongo_db_plugin. (`-m` option means with mongo_db_plugin)

Comment: can you share the resource where we can find all the flags(and thier use) we can pass to eos while building binaries from shell scripts. It is not documented here https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/install/build-from-source/shell-scripts/build-eosio-binaries

Comment: Run `scripts/eosio_build.sh -h` to see all available options.